# sed command - replace 2 words on a line by 2 words while keeping indentation of the second one

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to replace, in various Fortran files, the syntax of following loop :

```
   do 40, k=0,size_z+1
    do 30, j=0,size_y+1
     write(5,1000,advance='no') (x0(i,j,k),i=0,size_x)
     write(5,999,advance='no') x0(size_x+1,j,k)
     write(5,*)
30  continue
    if(k.ne.(size_z+1)) then
     write(5,*)
    endif
40 continue
```

by :

```
   do k=0,size_z+1
    do j=0,size_y+1
     write(5,1000,advance='no') (x0(i,j,k),i=0,size_x)
     write(5,999,advance='no') x0(size_x+1,j,k)
     write(5,*)
    end loop
    if(k.ne.(size_z+1)) then
     write(5,*)
    endif
   end loop
```

I succeed into replace "`do number,`" by "do" with :

```
sed "s/do\s[0-9]*,/do/g"
```

Now, I would like to replace "`30 continue`" and "`40 continue`" by "`end loop`" with setting the indentation of "`end loop`" equal to the indentation of "`continue`" (relatively to "`do`" keyword of the loop corresponding to this "`continue`" (see above the wanted replacement).

Unfortunately, I am not an expert to get this result with good indentation.

### Update 1

In my file, I realized that I have lines like this :

```
1000 format(1000(f15.11,1x))
1001 format('   Convergence = ',f11.9,' after ',i9,' steps ')
1002 format('   Wall Clock = ',f15.6)
```

So I would like to use the solution given and in the same time exclude the replacing of lines starting by a number and containing "`format(`"

I don't know how to perform the exclusion of this pattern while keeping the above solution which works. I tried :

```
sed -e 's:\(\s*do\s*\)[0-9]*,\s*:\1:' \
    -e '/^[0-9]/ s:[0-9 ]: :g' \
    -e '/format(/!s:continue:end loop:'
```

but this doesn't work. I get :

```
     format(    (f  .  , x))
     format('   Convergence = ',f  . ,' after ',i ,' steps ')
     format('   Wall Clock = ',f  . )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sed` as following.

```
sed -e 's:\(\s*do\s*\)[0-9]*,\s*:\1:' \
    -e '/continue/ s:[0-9 ]: :g' \
    -e 's:continue:end loop:' infile
```

1. `'s:\(\s*do\s*\)[0-9]*,\s*:\1:'`:

   - `\s*` matches any zero or more whitespaces
   - `\s*do\s*` matches `do` with zero or more whitespaces around followed by
   - `[0-9]*,\s*` zero or more numbers a comma `,` and zero or more whitespaces
   - `\(...\)` is make `\(\s*do\s*\)` match as a group of matches with `\1` as its [back reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html)
2. `'/continue/ s:[0-9 ]: :g'`:

   - `/continue/` matches lines if has a word *continue*, then
   - `s:[0-9 ]: :g'` replaces each number with a single space including space itself, this will keep indent of those lines
3. `'s:continue:end loop:'` replace `continue` with `end loop`
4. you can use any character as a delimiter instead of `:` which is not a part of your string or you can escape it.

Comment: -@AFSHIN Thanks a lot, it works. I didn't know the using of "**:**" character... could you explain what does '/^[0-9]/ s:[0-9 ]: :g'  ? why don't you use the slash character like **sed "s/pattern1/pattern2/g"** ? Regards

Comment: -@AFSHIN I forgot to tell you that I have also lines beginning by number and these lines must not be modified, see please my **UPDATE 1**, thanks

Comment: that is easy, please see update, just change `/^[0-9]/` part to `/continue/`, I hope you will not say I have another lines with _continue_ as well :D then you can use `/^[0-9].*continue/`